# Density of polynomials in $\cos t$ in $\mathcal{C}^0([0,\pi],\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, polynomials, fourier-analysis, approximation

I'm looking at the Fourier cosine transform, and as a preliminary I have to show that every $f$ in $\mathcal{C}^0([0,\pi],\mathbb R)$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of functions of the form $t\to P(\cos t) $ where $P$ is a polynomial over the real numbers.

I have looked at showing that every polynomial function verifies the property, starting to the monomials, and conclude using the Stone-Weierstrass approximation theorem, but my attempt based on using a power series representation of $\arccos$ didn't work out.

Anyone got any hints ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you assume that $\cos nt,\sin nt$ are dense in $\mathcal{C}^0[0,\pi]$?

Comment: I'm sure I can find the proof of the trigonometric Weierstrass approximation theorem in my notes, so yes.

Comment: Take any function and extend it to be even.

Comment: How does that work ?

Comment: @Groovy. As Pedro said, consider the function $g=f(|x|)$. This function is even, and if you can use trigonometric basis, you can approximate it as sum of terms of the form $\cos nt$. Now use addition formulas to show that $\forall n, \cos nt = p_n(\cos t)$ for some polynomial $p_n$ of order $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the ideas in the comments. The function $g(t)=f(\arccos t)$ is continuous in $[-1,1]$. $g$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials $p_n(t)$. Then $f(x)$ is the uniform limit of $p_n(\cos x)$.

Comment: Simple, and rather efficient. Thanks !